# Variable (constant) based on another variable in SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas

I need help with the following. My input dataset is as follows: [image]

If one of the values in the QC column is a FAIL, all of the values in the last column 'Final' should be REPEAT, irrespective of what other values are found in the QC column. Desired output dataset:  [image]

Thank you.

The following code does not give expected results as no condition is specified for other qc values.

```
data exp;
    set exp;
        if QC = "FAIL" then do;
            FINAL= "REPEAT";
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Please don't post photographs of data.  It looks like you already went to the trouble of typing the data, so just paste the actual text of the data into the question.  Don't waste your time and our time making a picture of it.

Comment: Sure, I will make a note of that. Thanks Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to process the entire data set to determine if no change is needed.

In this example there is a check if `FAIL` occurs in any row and then conditionally changes to `REPEAT`

```
data have;
  id+1;
  input value qc $  @@;  
  datalines;
. FAIL 1 PASS 0 PASS 1 PASS . FAIL
;

%let repeat_flag = 0;

data _null_;
  set have;
  where qc = 'FAIL';
  call symputx ('repeat_flag',1);
  stop;
run;

%if &repeat_flag %then %do;
  data have;
    set have;
    qc = 'REPEAT';
  run;
%end;
```

to set everything to REPEAT dependent on the number of FAILs, you can add a conditional to the DATA _NULL_.

```
data _null_;
  set have;
  where qc = 'FAIL';
  if _n_ >= 3;
  call symputx ('repeat_flag',1);
  stop;
run;
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question. How would the code change if I wanted a repeat flag only if there were 3 or more fails in the QC column? Instead of repeat flag on the first failure?

Comment: Hello @Richard, how would the code change if I wanted to use an if-else statement instead of just a repeat flag.. Repeat if there were 3 or more fails in the QC column else Pass?  My count statement works, following code does not.
%let pass_flag = 0;
data _null_;
  set exp;
  if count ge 3 then call symputx ('repeat_flag',1);
   else call symputx ('pass_flag',1);
  stop;
run;
%if &repeat_flag %then %do;
  data exp;
    set exp;
     Final = 'REPEAT';
  run;
%end;
%if &pass_flag %then %do;
  data exp;
    set exp;
     Final = 'PASS';
  run;
%end;

Comment: Hello @Richard, the if statement "if _n_ >= 3;" does not work. I get the following warning and error: WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference REPEAT_FLAG not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference REPEAT_FLAG not resolved.
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand
       is required. The condition was: &repeat_flag
ERROR: Skipping to next %END statement.

Comment: you probably removed the line before the DATA step. you need `%let repeat_flag = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the data twice.  The first time to figure out if there are any QC failures.  The second time to get the records again so you can attach the new variable and write them to the output dataset.  The first pass can stop as soon as you find any failure.

```
data want ;
  do while(not eof1);
    set have end=eof1;
    if qc = 'FAIL' then do;
      final='REPEAT';
      eof1=1;
    end;
  end;
  do while(not eof2);
    set have end=eof2;
    output;
  end;
  stop;
run;
```

Comment: This works as well. Thank you, Tom.